# How to make smooth plot with matrix that don't have the same column and line

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB so i don't know many aspects and capabilities of the language.

I have these matrix

```
Z = [60:5:165];
Vmetr = [10;2.2;0.1;2.7;10;0;2.3;10;0.1;1.9;10;0.6;1.1;10;1.3;0.5;10;2;0;10;2.6;0];
```

So when I give as a command

```
plot(Z,Vmetr,'r.','Markersize',18),hold on
plot(Z,Vmetr)
```

I get the following graph [image]

I want the second plot to be smoothed and curve and to reach all the way down to `0`.
So how can I create a smoothed and curved version of this graph keeping the dots as they are now?

Comment: [1D Interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/1-d-interpolation.html)

Comment: You need to increase your sampling frequency. If you can't do that, then try `interp1` using the `'pchip'` method.

Comment: Although i ave no idea how to do this, i will try to find out... :D Thank you!